# cleaner php code

Tags: php

```
if (isset($_GET['sort_by']) && strlen($_GET['sort_by']) > 0)
{
    $sort_by = $_GET['sort_by'];
}
else
{
     $sort_by = 'desc';  
}
```

how can I rewrite that so it looks cleaner and has less lines.. I love one liners hehe

Answer (score 5):

The first option is just to move the default value outside the if block and thereby remove the else. If you want to keep the conditions in the if statement this (probably) the best as 
it retains the clarity that is lost if you more it into a statment using the conditional (ternary) operator.

```
$sort_by = 'desc'
if (isset($_GET['sort_by']) && strlen($_GET['sort_by']) > 0){
    $sort_by = $_GET['sort_by'];
}
```

Although as strlen won't return less than 0, you can remove the `> 0`

```
$sort_by = 'desc'
if (isset($_GET['sort_by']) && strlen($_GET['sort_by']) ){
    $sort_by = $_GET['sort_by'];
}
```

Another option is to move everything onto one line and use the conditional operator. The downside is that it takes terseness (In my option) far to far and starts to put too much one one line.

```
$sort_by =  isset($_GET['sort_by']) && strlen($_GET['sort_by']) ? $_GET['sort_by'] : 'desc';
```

If you changed the functionality slightly so that you could use `empty()` the conditional operator becomes usable due to the reduced length. The issue is that the string "0" is treated as being empty.

```
$sort_by =  !empty($_GET['sort_by']) ? $_GET['sort_by'] : 'desc';
```

Comment: I think it should be `!empty()` (or switch the branches).

Comment: @Felix I just noticed that. :)

Comment: I'd also keep a list of possible values for "sort_by" to avoid SQL injections

Comment: only issue with this is that ?sort_by=adasdf breaks the site

Answer (score 1):

```
$sort_by = in_array( $_GET['sort_by'], array( 'asc', 'desc' ) ) ? $_GET['sort_by'] : 'desc';
```

this also checks the vailidity

Answer (score 0):

regardless of how you rewrite it (and Yacoby's got a good one-liner for you), if you do this often (null and strlen check query string vars), you should probably wrap it in a function with an option "default value" parameter).

ie. `function getQueryStringVar($key, $defaultValue = '') { ...`

Comment: i love it thanks gentlemen  (no offence to female intelligence)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would add that one-liners does not automatically mean cleaner code, however Yacoby did a great job of cleaning up the code (as well as making it a one liner). However I would tidy up his one liner to read....

$sort_by =  empty($_GET['sort_by']) ? 'desc' : $_GET['sort_by'];

Simply because the ! symbol can sometimes be missed by someone reading the code - I think this is a clearer one liner in my opinion :)